# using comma to rename a model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm using comma gem to download my contacts into csv format. However there's a requirement in which I'm required to rename the attribute name from first_name to First Name and I'm wondering how do I do that.

My comma DSL in my contact model is as follows

```
comma do

  id
  first_name
  last_name
  email
  phone

end
```

so for first_name and last_name I'm looking for some option that would allow me to convert
first_name => "First Name" and last_name => "Last Name" something like that, any suggestions?

By the way, I'm using Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

Update:

In my controller, I have a select query that uses some joins as well, for instance:

UserJob.joins(:rounds, :works).select("user_job.first_name AS firstname, user_job.last_name AS lastname ... ")

So comma looks for `first_name` in the object's attributes but since it's been modified in the query as `firstname` it generates a missing attribute error so I'm wondering how do I tell comma that `first_name` is actually `firstname`.

Comment: You cannot have spaces in attribute names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the headers "First Name" and "Last Name" in the CSV, you can specify the header directly:

```
comma do

  id
  first_name 'First Name' 
  last_name 'Last Name'
  email
  phone

end
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.
however say i have a query in which i'm using AS to change the attribute, then how do i tell comma that first_name is firstname actually, otherwise it will generate a missing attribute error.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot do that, you can only specify a different CSV header name . Comma expects methods, attributes, associations, etc and it does not have a "rename" feature. Can you update your post with some more context what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: right, i found a workaround for that in my controller. Anyway thanks for clarification.